# What address clause for a GNAT.Sockets.Selector_Type

Tags: sockets, ada

I'm using a `Selector_Type` in my code.

On one hand, the `Selector_Type` from `GNAT.Sockets` [comes with](http://gnuada.sourceforge.net/source-gcc-4.2.2/g-socket__ads.html)  the pragma:

```
pragma Volatile (Selector_Type);
```

On the other hand, Gnatckeck's [rule 9.1.1.2](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/asis/html/gnatcheck_rm/gnatcheck_rm/predefined_rules.html#volatile-objects-without-address-clauses) applied to my code will raise

> volatile object with no address clause [Volatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses]

because of the pragma.

This topic isn't handled in [wikibook's example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/GNAT.Sockets_examples) nor do I address this issue anywhere in my base code.

So, what address should I use for my selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t. The `Selector_Type` is volatile because it’s an interface to the operating system, and may (will) change without any action on the part of the Ada code.

My trial example was

```ada
package Rules is
   type Selector is limited private;
private
   type Selector is null record with Volatile;
   S : Selector;
end Rules;
```

checked as

```
$ gnatcheck --show-rule rules.ads -rules +RVolatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses
rules.ads:5:04: volatile object with no address clause [Volatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses]
```

It seems that you have to say what rules you want checked, why not just don’t select this one?

Alternatively, if you have control of the source,  you can apply an [exemption](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/asis/html/gnatcheck_rm/gnatcheck_rm/rule_exemption.html).

In this case, this would look like

```ada
package Rules is
   type Selector is limited private;
private
   type Selector is null record with Volatile;
   pragma Annotate (Gnatcheck, Exempt_On,
                    "Volatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses",
                    "only a demo!");
   S : Selector;
   pragma Annotate (Gnatcheck, Exempt_Off,
                    "Volatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses");
   T : Selector;
end Rules;
```

and now it checks as

```
$ gnatcheck --show-rule rules.ads -rules +RVolatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses
rules.ads:11:04: volatile object with no address clause [Volatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses]
```

(line 11 is `T`'s unexempted declaration; no complaint about `S`'s declaration on line 8).

---

Note:

Apologies for earlier versions of this answer, which had a fundamental misunderstanding. gnatcheck supports the rule just fine, so long as you read it properly: it’s about volatile *objects* with no address clause, not volatile *types*.

Comment: The rule itself is relevant and shall not remain unverified on the code base. But in the case of a false positive, I guess I'll go with a [rule exemption](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/asis/html/gnatcheck_rm/gnatcheck_rm/rule_exemption.html). Would you update your answer with rule exemptions so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention you in my comment. Don't know if this triggered a notification.

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer! I've updated a bit my question. Your code would raise the `Volatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses` warning, if activated, on any instantiation of the `Selector` type without an address clause. This could be a perfect update to your question to exempt exactly the warning I've asked about (which has to be exempted for instantiation of the type and not on definition). BTW, to see the name of the rules, you could add `--show-rule` to your gnatcheck invocation.

Comment: As I said in the answer, "I haven’t been able to get gnatcheck (Darwin, GCC 9.1.0 + ASIS GPL 2018) to report this "violation" at all". Maybe ASIS GPL 2019 will.

Comment: OK, I didn't perfectly grap the "at all". I've never used ASIS. Though, adding an instantiation of the `Selector` in rules.ads, I've been able to generate the warning `gnatcheck rules.ads  -rules +RVolatile_Objects_Without_Address_Clauses` with every version of gnat I have at hand (from GNAT 7.1.7 up to GNAT 19.1). Is this a specificity of ASIS?

Comment: gnatcheck is one of the tools that comes with/uses ASIS. You are using GNAT Pro, I can only use the GPL/FSF versions. None of them report this, perhaps it’s one of the benefits of being a Pro customer! (I guess you’re not supported any longer, or you’d be asking AdaCore- ?)

Comment: We are still supported but as a constant SO user, I wanted to make the Ada community a bit more visible and make all of us benefit from this topic. Anyway I'll ask adacore about this now that the problem appears clearer to me. Might even be considered as a bug : instantiation of Selector_Type shouldn't be reported as violation.